# How to use OR in a URL?

Tags: php, html

I'm making a search in PHP and for a specific field I need to search one or more variable possible values. Eg. I need to display results of people with "Black" and "Red" hair (and my variable is "hair"). At this time I only know how to do it with one value. Eg.

```
...search.php&hair=black
```

Thank you!

Comment: In the title, you write "or", but in the question, you write "and". Which is it, people with black and red hair, or black or red hair?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can turn `$_GET['hair']` into an array by using square brackets (`[]`):

```
search.php?hair[]=black&hair[]=red
```

`$_GET['hair']` value:

```
[hair] => Array
    (
        [0] => black
        [1] => red
    )
```

Answer (score 4):

The query string is generally a list of key-value pairs, separated by ampersands or semicolons, but you can use any format you want, though you will have to parse non-standard formats. Note the ampersands do not mean "and", they're simply separators. Correspondingly, there's nothing that means "or" in a query string.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
http://link/search.php?hair[]=black&hair[]=red
```

And then, you can retrieve the array with:

```
$_GET['hair']
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

/search.php?hair=black,red,green

Then in the script, you do this:

```
$terms = explode(',', $_GET['hair']);
// Now $terms is an array containing the values: black, red, and green.
// You can do your search based on those terms.
```